# Error during execution of Postgresql query on Cube data type column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am new to Postgesql. I have created a table with fields `(Id integer, name text, url text, vector cube)` named `images`.

Now I want to search K nearest values to a new cube variable using `<->` (euclidean distance ) operator. My query is as follows(I have assumed that data column is 3D):

```
Select * 
from images 
order by vector <-> cube(array[0.5, 0.3, 0.2]) 
limit 5
```

But following error occurs:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: cube <-> cube
LINE 1: Select * from test order by data <-> cube(array[0.5, 0.3, 0.2...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 38
```

Kindly do help me. Thanks. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and Postgresql version 9.5.19.

Screen shots of my table and error are attached below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match the query. The query orders by `vector` and the error orders by `data`. You need to have the cube extension, which I gues you have, and data/vector should also be of datatype cube, which it seems vector is.

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: My version is 9.5.19. The doc shows that, <-> operator is not available on this version. Now I have upgraded the version, let me see again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cube` extension in postgres 9.5 does not have the `<->` operator. You can use `cube_distance` instead. Here are the relevant docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/cube.html

Comment: Hi wobr. Thanks for your answer, I have upgraded to 10.11 but error is still there.

Comment: You will need to upgrade the extension. Something like `ALTER EXTENSION cube UPDATE;`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-alterextension.html

Comment: That super cool. After updating postgres to 10.11, I have updated the cube using 'Alter Extension cube Update 1.2' and my problem was solved. Thanks again.